# I want to output a string in orthogonal 5×5

Tags: php, string, orthogonal

If I have a string for example $msj="hello everyone how are you";
I want to output the string in this way

hello

evryo

nehow

areyo

uxxxx

Without counting spaces and if the string has less than 25 charecters to put X instead
And greater than 25 to cut them

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any effort made by OP

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show what you've tried so far and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help.

```
<?php
    $str = "hello everyone how are you";

    $len = strlen($str);
    $ctr = 0;

    for($i=0; $i< $len; $i++)
    {

        if($str[$i] != ' ')
        {
            echo $str[$i];
            $ctr++;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

        if($ctr % 5 == 0)
        {
            echo "<br>";

        } 
        if($ctr == 25)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    $temp = $ctr;

    for($i=0; $i< 25- $ctr; $i++)
    {
        echo 'x';
        $temp ++;

        if($temp %5 == 0)
        {
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove spaces and make chunks of 5 letters

```
$msj = "hello everyone how are you";

// remove spaces
$msj = str_replace(' ', '', $msj);

// append X if needed
$msj = str_pad($msj, 25, "X");

// cut off if needed
$msj = substr($msj, 0, 25);

// make chunks
echo chunk_split($msj, 5, "\n");
```